# Django iniline widget - Refresh inline widget every time the "Add another" button is clicked

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using the [jsoneditor](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor) plugin as a widget for all JSON fields, but when the jsoneditor widget is added after clicking the "Add another [model]" button, the widgets render and other init functions, including the JS files, are not called/loaded properly, therefore the html loads, but the functionality doesn't work properly.

What I want to know is how can I reload the entire jsoneditor/inline widget that is added after "Add another" button is clicked.

I am successfully calling the following JS functions when an inline is added and removed:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).on('formset:added', function(event, $row, formsetName) {
    console.log('Formset added');
  });

  $(document).on('formset:removed', function(event, $row, formsetName) {
    console.log('Formset removed');
  });
})(django.jQuery);
```

But I want to know from within the JavaScript above itself, how do I reload the jsoneditor widget added.

Here is the widget for reference:

```
class JSONEditorWidget(django.forms.Widget):
    template_name = 'django_json_widget.html'

    class Media:
        css = {'all': (_STATIC_URL + 'dist/jsoneditor.min.css',)}
        js = (_STATIC_URL + 'dist/jsoneditor.min.js',)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        context = {
            'data': value,
            'name': name
        }

    return django_safestring.mark_safe(django_loader.render_to_string(
        self.template_name, context)
    )
```

Comment: Just reload the page... but if you dont want to reload the entire page you should use JS to make it

Comment: Id like to do it without reloading the page. Just want to reload the widget added

Comment: django only will answer you if you go to the server call him, because he works on server side... you could use ajax to prevent the page reload, but i dont know if ajax will workout well on your case, try remove the JS import from jsoneditor and import it again with javascript (remove html element and add it again after you click the button)